# problem with using web component which extends native html element in angular

Tags: angular, web-component

I am trying to use a web component which extends native HTML element, in my Angular app.

following is the code of my web component.

```
class TestButton extends HTMLButtonElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and this is how I am defining it in my index.html file

```
window.customElements.define('test-element', testElementM.TestElement);
```

In my app.component.ts file I am setting the attribute value as follows

```
ngOnInit() {
    document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('my-test-name', 'test');
}
```

In index.html I am testing if the attribute is changed or not.

```
testElementM.TestElement.prototype.attributeChangedCallback = function() {
    debugger;
}
```

But I attributeChangedCallback never gets called. Can anyone please help me with this?

Following is the url for stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-klj2ud?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: Can u provide sample on https://stackblitz.com ?

Comment: @BenceUszkai Sure. give me some time, I'll create one

Comment: @BenceUszkai I have added the stackblitz, but unfortunately there is an error that I am not able to get rid of.

Comment: The use of attributeChangedCallback requires a static observedAttributes property.